# nested table not taking 100% height of parent td

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have created a nested table by writing a `table` inside a `td`. I want that the `table` inside the `td` should take the 100% height of the parent `td`. I have tried `height:100%`, but not working.

Is there any way to make the inner table to take the 100% height or this is the `table` default behaviour?

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This will succeed only if the parent element has a fixed height, I believe.

Comment: table {height: 100%} works

Comment: @VXp `table{height:100%}` not working as I mentioned in the question

Comment: I can see it's working just fine. :) Chrome

Comment: i agree with @VXp it's working on chrome, what are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height: 100%; 
}

td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
}

table table{
 height: 100%;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/qvcbbvft/13/)

Comment: That doesn't work in Chrome or Safari. Probably other browsers too.

Comment: Works on firefox (mac)... let see on the other browsers to make a fix

Answer (score 1):

add `height:100%` to table.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

For some weird reason, setting `height: 1px;` to the outer table fixes the problem.

It looks like a bug in specification (since the problems is present in all the browsers, and the workaround works in all the major browsers as well).

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.outer-table {
  height: 1px;
}

.inner-table {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="outer-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>
        <table class="inner-table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
              <td>foobar</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: totally weird but it works on browsers. It still doesn't work in outlook though.